# Drawing bitmap from memory

Tags: c++, c, winapi, bitmap, bmp

I need to create the HBITMAP.

Here lies the problem. I have the bmp file's content in memory.

I know how to create a HBITMAP if the bitmap was as a resource.
But since it is in memory, I don't know how to do it.

I do it like this (if in resource) : [Link](http://www.functionx.com/win32/Lesson14.htm)

```
    hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &Ps);

    // Load the bitmap from the resource
    bmpExercising = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_EXERCISING));
    // Create a memory device compatible with the above DC variable
    MemDCExercising = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
         // Select the new bitmap
         SelectObject(MemDCExercising, bmpExercising);

    // Copy the bits from the memory DC into the current dc
    BitBlt(hDC, 10, 10, 450, 400, MemDCExercising, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    // Restore the old bitmap
    DeleteDC(MemDCExercising);
    DeleteObject(bmpExercising);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &Ps);
```

Please guide me on how to do it if it were a memory resource.
Somehow change `char img[10000]` into a resource ?
Here, `img` is the memory contraining the contents of the bitmap.

Comment: CreateDIBitmap is what you need, but it's a complicated function. Look around for some sample code.

Comment: can you show me some example ? I really searched a lot...

Comment: [createDIBSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [GetDIBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @c.adhityaa Didn't find any sample I could recommend. As I said it's a complicated function and a lot depnds on what format your 'memory resource' is in. I guess you're just going to have to work your way through MSDN. When you have some actual code I'm sure people here will help you fix any problems. Remember take the time to describe your problem carefully and precisely, that's not something you've done this time, which is why you've got three different answers.

Comment: Sorry, was in a hurry then... will rephrase the question better sometime now... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's remove a little innocent gotcha:

```
hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &Ps);

// Load the bitmap from the resource
bmpExercising = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_EXERCISING));
// Create a memory device compatible with the above DC variable
MemDCExercising = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
     // Select the new bitmap
HOBJECT oldbmp = SelectObject(MemDCExercising, bmpExercising); //<<<<save it for later ...

// Copy the bits from the memory DC into the current dc
BitBlt(hDC, 10, 10, 450, 400, MemDCExercising, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

// Restore the old bitmap
SelectObject(MemDCExercising, oldbmp); //<<<... DeleteDC will leak memory if it holds a resource
DeleteDC(MemDCExercising);
DeleteObject(bmpExercising);
EndPaint(hWnd, &Ps);
```

Now, an HBITMAP is (conceptually speaking) a pointer to an internal structure that holds a "pointer" (in fact is much more a stream) towards the GDI memory space you cannot access.

A "memory bitmap" is not represented into your program as a memory buffer that belogs to your program, but as ... an HBITMAP obtained with [CreateCompatibleBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183488%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), where the HDC parameter id the DC the bitmap has to be compatible with. (usially a screen, window or painting DC).

You can cerate an initialized bitmap passing a buffer containing initial data, or get the data a bitmap holds with [CreateBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [GetBitmapBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144850%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In any case, these are your local copy of the bitmap data, not the "live bitmap" GDI draws in.

Note also that the internal structure of those data depends on the format (how many bits per pixel on how many planes and with or without a palette) the bitmap needs to have, and that, to avoid performance penalty in the Blit process, it must coincide with the format used by your screen setup.

This does not necessarily have to be the same as the one the bitmap has when saved into a "bmp" file.

Comment: I tried CreateBitmap... But I don't understand a few parametrs... (eg. cplane, lpvBits)... So, could you please give some code to demonstrate this ?

Comment: GetBitmapBits is superseded by [GetDIBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getdibits) mentioned in the comments above,  which has a better explanation of parms. That code looks like a classic double buffering example. :)